# Retrofit2 + RxJava2 Flowable for HTTPs request

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Now I am trying to understand how to use RxJava2 library with Retrofit2.

My Api service:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET
    Observable<String> getObservable(@Url String url);

    @GET
    Flowable<String> getFlowable(@Url String url);
}
```

and main activity:

```
mApiService.getObservable("https://google.com")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull String s) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"onNextObservable");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                       Log.d(TAG,"onErrorObservable");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d(TAG,"onCompleteObservable");
                    }
                });


mApiService.getFlowable("https://google.com")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new FlowableSubscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Subscription s) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onSubscribeFlowable");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onNextFlowable");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onErrorFlowable");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d(TAG,"onCompleteFlowable");
            }
        });
```

In my log I see:

- onNextObservable
- onSubscribeFlowable
- onCompleteObservable

Why I don't see onNextFlowable? I can't get a response from Flowable. Maybe there is a more compact method of writing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a URL is something that return only one result or failed (more like `Single` or `Maybe`). `Observable` work too. But `Flowable` doesn't make sens here.

Anyway, try to add `s.request(1)` in `onSubscribe(...)` of the `Flowable`.

`Flowable` has the notion of "backpressure". You have to *ask* for data.

Comment: Yes, this method works. Thank you! I didn't see the method being mentioned somewhere. But if I want to get 100 Mb data from firebase and firebase gives data in portions. Need I use Flowable? And how to set up Flowable to receive the data?